# Default position and size of front-end windows (in Windows 7)

Tags: front-end

I'm running *Mathematica* 8 on Windows 7.  When I start the *Mathematica* front end, I would like the menu bar and the blank notebook that opens to appear at a different position and with a different size from what they do by default.

(By default the menu bar appears at the top of the screen and the blank notebook appears below it on the left side of the screen.  I would like to try having the menu bar and notebook appear resized to about 350px wide and positioned in the upper right corner of the screen:
[image]
.)

Comment: did you try playing with the  `WindowSize` and `WindowMargins` options in `Global Preferences > Notebook Options> Window Properties> ` in  `Option Inspector` in `Format Menu`?

Comment: @kguler When I change, for example `WindowOpacity`, the windows' opacity changes, but when I change `WindowSize`, nothing seems to change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you Nilo for pointing me in a direction that was productive.  I used the software [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/).  A recorder wasn't necessary.

The following script does the job.  I set the width of the windows to 350px.  My screens have a total width of 1600px*2=3200px, so the left edges of the windows have X coordinate 3200-350=2850.

```
; start Mathematica and put it in the corner with the shortcut Windows key+C
#c::                           
   Run C:\Users\Andrew\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar\Wolfram Mathematica 8.lnk
   Sleep, 100
   WinWait, Untitled-1, 
   IfWinNotActive, Untitled-1, , WinActivate, Untitled-1, 
   WinWaitActive, Untitled-1, 
   WinMove, ,, 2850, 75, 350, 300
   WinMove, Wolfram Mathematica,, 0,0, 350
   WinMove, Wolfram Mathematica,, 2850, 0
return
```

For the `Run` command I used the taskbar shortcut because I have *Mathematica* pinned to my taskbar and running the .exe created a new taskbar icon beside the pinned one instead of just activating the pinned icon.  Note that if *Mathematica* is already running when this script is executed the result may not be as expected.

Answer (score 5):

( Think out of the box? ) - Start Mathematica with a Windows macro ( any recorder will do ). First record the start of MMa and the resizing / moving of the menu bar and so on, then use the recording to start MMa.